# Validate an array using Laravels Validator

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Is it possible to use Laravels [`validate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) function to validate an array, and if so how?

I'm not interested in validating input or a  request, I just wanna use Laravels great validation syntax on a completely ordinary array.

#### Example

```
$arr = array(
    'name' => 'David',
    'year' => 1986,
    'score' => 532
    );

$this->validate($arr, [
    'name' => 'required',
    'year' => 'numeric',
    'score' => 'required|numeric'
    ]);
```

This will throw an error

> Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request

- Laravel version: 5.1
- PHP version: 7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
$arr = array(
    'name' => 'David',
    'year' => 1986,
    'score' => 532
    );

$validator = Validator::make($arr, [
    'name' => 'required',
    'year' => 'numeric',
    'score' => 'required|numeric'
    ]);
```

and

```
if ($validator ->passes()){
/* True condition here*/
}
```

Comment: D'oh. Obviously. Thank you - will accept your answer when I can

Comment: @Daniel OK. Did I get your question correctly? Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

**$this->validate()** method requires 'Request' as first argument.
To use **$this->validate()** method you should merge request data before you call **$this->validate()**.

```
$request->merge(array(
    'name' => 'David',
    'year' => 1986,
    'score' => 532
));

$this->validate($request->only(['name', 'year', 'score']), [
    'name' => 'required',
    'year' => 'numeric',
    'score' => 'required|numeric'
]);
```

P.S. Don't forget to inject `Request` service to your method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$validator = Validator::make(
        $arr,
        array(
            'name' => 'required',
            'year' => 'numeric',
            'score' => 'required|numeric'
        )
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        print_r($errors);
    }
```